# Baire space, analytic sets

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

I am reading a proof from the book 'Banach spaces and descriptive set theory, lemma 7.2' and it uses the following argument:
If $A\subset X$ is analytic and $X$ is a closed subspace of the Baire space $\mathcal{N}$, then $A$ can be seen as an analytic subset of $\mathcal{N}$. My question is where did this step come from?

Comment: what is your definition of analytic? Does it easily/trivially imply that every closed set is analytic, and that the intersection of a closed set and an analytic set is analytic.?

Comment: So far it's been the continuous image of a Polish space, but I am aware there are many alternative formulations. Closed sets are Borel so they are analytic..?

Comment: well, this definition makes it trivial, I think, if $A$ is analytic, i.e. being a continuous image of a Polish space, then it is analytic, regardless of the bigger space in which it sits (as long as it gets the same subspace topology).

Comment: This is not true as far as I know. For the definition to make sense, it must be  the range of a continuous image between Polish spaces.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, it's the definition which @PedroSánchezTerraf said.

Comment: @Jared Indeed, every Borel subset of a Polish space is analytic.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf so $A$ is analytic in $X$, there is a Polish space $Y$ and a continuous $f:Y\to X$ such that $f(Y)=A$. Now, the Baire space $\mathcal{N}$ is a Polish space, and $X\subset \mathcal{N}$, so you could consider the same $f$ with $f:Y\to\mathcal N$ and $f(Y)=A$. Or if you prefer , formally consider $j:X\to\mathcal N$, $j(x)=x$, and $(j\circ f):Y\to\mathcal N$ with $(j\circ f)(Y)=A$.